# Debug DLL with Labview and Visual studio

Tags: labview

I wrote a C_Wrapper for a DLL (C ++).
This DLL is imported in Labview.
Since there are many problems with this import in Labview, I would like to know:

Is it possible with Labview and Visual Studio to debug this DLL step for step

Comment: 'LabVIEW.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2012\LabVIEW.exe'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio navigate to Debug->Attach to Process then select labview.exe (note: at that time your labview code which uses dll should be already ran). Now you will be able to catch all labview calls to your dll and debug it inside of VS environment (note: you can see all data passed from labview, put your breakpoints into c++ code, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed possible. I suppose you already have a visual studio project to build your DLL.

Go to your project's property pages and set the Debugging->Command parameter to the location of LabVIEW.exe (usually installed at C:\Program Files\National Instruments\{Your LabVIEW version}\LabVIEW.exe)

Then just hit F5 to start LabVIEW under the debugger.

Comment: An alternative is also to attach the debugger to an existing instance of LabVIEW.exe

Comment: I can not debug.
Although he starts Laview but not in Visual Studio debug mode

Comment: I have a message:

'LabVIEW.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Comment: The message about missing PDB files is normal, you don't have LabVIEW and windows system DLLs symbols installed. 
Try running a VI that uses your DLL, you should see a message about loading the DLL and its debug symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. I tried it with Visual Studio 2015 and LabVIEW 2015

**Configure you project in Visual Studio** (taken from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/605a12zt.aspx)

1. Right-click the project node in the Solution Explorer and select Properties. Go to the Debug tab.
2. Make sure that the Configuration field at the top of the window is set to Debug.
3. Go to Configuration Properties / Debugging.
4. In the Debugger to launch list, choose Local Windows Debugger
5. In the Command box, add the fully-qualified path name of the application: C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2015\LabVIEW.exe
6. Set Attach to Yes

**Configure LabVIEW DLL call**

7. Make sure your VI calls a DLL from /Debug/ folder and not from /Release/ folder

**Start Debugging**

8. Run Debug in Visual Studio. Make sure LabVIEW process is attached
9. Add breakpoints if needed
10. Start your VI